# Removing an injection using regex

Tags: php, regex, bash, sed

I'm looking to sed this specific line from line 1 of about 16,000+ files.

Beginning of the injection is:

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS`

Middle of the injection is:
`7860msvd`

And end of the injection is:
`oqggbrtstz-1; ?>
```

This content is in 1 line only (the first)

Not sure how to do it but what I have here is the following;

`sed -i -e '1 s/.*<\?php if\(\!isset\(\$GLOBALS\.*7860msvd.*oqggbrtstz-1; ?>//g'`

`error: sed: -e expression #1, char 67: Unmatched ( or \(`

Any help would be awesome.

Comment: could be multiple injections in one file? could be here parts what are needed without e.g. the midlle or end?

Comment: is it 1 line or (like sample seems to show) several line as pattern ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missing to literal some special character like `?` and using `-r` get expect result

```
sed -ri  '1 s/.*<\?php if\(\!isset\(\$GLOBALS.*7860msvd.*oqggbrtstz-1; \?>//g' File

   -r, --regexp-extended

          use extended regular expressions in the script.
```

Comment: @Scivic,You are most welcome. You can accept it so that I will get a green tick.

Comment: how can it work on a multiline here sed take only 1 line at a time ? Sample show several line between `.*<\?php `and `; ?>` and no new line/buffer loading.

Comment: @NeronLeVelu, I think those content are present in single line like that I have posted the answer .

Comment: how to run it on all php files ?

Comment: above command and using regex `*.php` . Instead of passing single file pass  `*.php`

Comment: `sed -ri  '1 s/.*<\?php if\(\!isset\(\$GLOBALS.*7860msvd.*oqggbrtstz-1; \?>//g'  *.php` look like this

Answer (score 1):

@josifoski is right, don't escape the parenthesis. Minor correction to his answer to avoid stripping off code *before* the injection:

`sed -i -e '1 s/<\?php if(\!isset(\$GLOBALS.*7860msvd.*oqggbrtstz-1; \?>//g'`

Comment: Whether or not the parens should be escaped depends on the `sed` dialect.

Answer (score 1):

The one important missing answer is "don't do that".  Harden the site before you do anything else. Then restore the site from known-good backups, or redeploy the site from version control.

Finding and patching the *known* problem is not a proper solution. It will remove one obvious symptom, but do nothing to prevent you from being hacked again. And with any substantial code base, chances are the intruder left other surprises which you just haven't noticed yet.

Answer (score 0):

syntax correction of your command

```
sed -i -e '1 s/.*<\?php if(\!isset(\$GLOBALS\.*7860msvd.*oqggbrtstz-1; \?>//g'
```

no need to escape () when not present backreference and missing escaping to ?