# Website hacked, how to remove malicious code with SED / GREP

Tags: php, ssh, sed

a website of mine is hacked. In every php file a line of code is added. I wont post the complete code here, but it starts with:

```
<?php if(!isset($GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"])) { $ua=strtolower($_SERVER["\x48\124\x54\120\x5f\125\x53\105\x52\137\x41\107\x45\116\x54"]); if ((! strstr($ua,"\x6d\163\x69\145")) and (! strstr($ua,"\x72\166\x3a\61\x31"))) $GLOBALS["\x61\156\x75\156\x61"]=1; } ?><?php $yudqgxmnlr =
```

and ends with:

```
 $gzagexgpdc=substr($yudqgxmnlr,(34129-24016),(83-71)); $gzagexgpdc($xarchajboj, $ukumkvvgai, NULL); $gzagexgpdc=$ukumkvvgai; $gzagexgpdc=(759-638); $yudqgxmnlr=$gzagexgpdc-1; ?>
```

I've tried finding and replacing with some ssh commands, but it doesnt seem to work. (Read: my lack of ssh knowledge gets in the way).

This is my latest atempt:

```
sed -i '<?php if(!isset*gzagexgpdc-1; ?>//g’ *.php
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Removing an injection using regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26013782/removing-an-injection-using-regex)

Comment: Just re-deploy the site.

Comment: I wouldn't do this remotely. Download all the files, back it up, do a S&R in your editor, then send it back to the remote site.

Comment: Also, find out _how_ it was hacked. If there is a sec hole, it may happen again.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best methods to clean up a hacked site with no clean version available?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6337976/best-methods-to-clean-up-a-hacked-site-with-no-clean-version-available)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hacked Site - SSH to remove a large body of javascript from 200+ files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55407263/hacked-site-ssh-to-remove-a-large-body-of-javascript-from-200-files)

Answer (score 1):

You can try this : https://github.com/daniyalahmadk/RMCI

Just need to put that code in box and hit submit, it will search code from files and remove them all once.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `s/` at the start.

```
sed 's/<?php if(\!isset.*gzagexgpdc-1; ?>//g' *.php
```

OR

```
sed -r 's/<\?php if\(!isset.*gzagexgpdc-1; \?>//g' *.php
```

Add `-i` parameter to save the changes made.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried it on one subdir and found out these files ended with a different code so i tried: 

sed -i 's/<\?php if(!isset.*-1; \?>//g' *.php
But this didnt work...

Am I missing something?

Comment: did'nt work how (too much removed or not enough like not all lines, or nothing at all ...) ?

Comment: Nothing removed, but file-timestamp was edited... Didnt get any feedback trough terminal

Comment: remove the `-i` parameter. `i` saves the changes made to that file. It won't display the output in the terminal.

Comment: What do you mean Avinash Raj? I tried it without the -i but then it just shows all the files content?

Comment: yep, `-i` will save the changes made. At first without using the `-i` param we need to check the output produced is correct or not.

Comment: When i do this: sed 's/<\?php if(!isset.*-1; \?>//g' *.php it just shows the complete files: not just the part i want to remove.

Comment: try `sed 's/<?php if(\!isset.*gzagexgpdc-1; ?>//g' file` or `sed -r 's/<\?php if\(!isset.*gzagexgpdc-1; \?>//g' file`

Comment: first option (sed 's/<?php if(\!isset.*gzagexgpdc-1; ?>//g’ *.php) shows nothing, second option shows the complete files again.

Comment: so use the first option with `-i` param. First check the file for the part you want to remove.

Comment: Unfortunately... No luck.. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
find . -name "*.php" -print0 | xargs -0 sed -ri '1s/^<\?php if\(!isset\(\$GLOBALS\[.*-1; \?>//' *.php
```