# Replace first line of php scripts if over 250 characters

Tags: linux, command-line, grep

I have a lot of files that got injected on a shared server.  I need to replace the first line of all PHP files with an opening php tag if the first line exceeds 250 characters.  Is there a simple-ish command that does this in linux?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Website hacked, how to remove malicious code with SED / GREP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28317990/website-hacked-how-to-remove-malicious-code-with-sed-grep)

Comment: See also http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/314002/how-to-cope-with-help-ive-been-hacked-questions

Answer (score 0):

Use `sed`:

```
sed -i '1s/^.\{250,\}$/<?php/g' *.php
```

This will replace only the first line (`1` before the `s/`) if over 250 chars (`.\{250, \}`) with `<?php` in all php files in current directory.