# How can I remove a malicious line of code and replace it with the opening php tag using regex, in multiple files?

Tags: regex, sed

I use a domain in my server for dev websites, I have put them all as subdomains in the same domain, like client1.mydomain.com, client2.mydomain.com, and so on. Well, all of these websites were targeted by a malicious code, it seems it's always the very first line in the files - all the files in the sites it seems.

I'm looking for a way of removing this malicious line of code, but replace it with the opening php tag - or anything that will only remove the malicious code and not my opening php tag where it exists.

Here's what the malicious line looks like:

```
<?php $vhilmjpo = 'x53 105 x53 137 ........ (it goes like this with random strings and numbers for a long while) .... (and it finishes with the ending php tag) ... ?>
```

The problem is that sometimes my files start with the php opening tag and sometimes it's plain html, so I can't just remove the complete line and replace with `<?php`

So, sometimes, the files start like this:

`<?php $vhilmjpo = 'x53 .......?><?php`

and sometimes it's like this:

`<?php $vhilmjpo = 'x53 .......?><div class="whatever">`

I have used sed in the past, and it proves to be of great help, but I don't know how to do it for this particular case.

Something like this could work if all of my files had the malicious line on a line of its own, but that's not the case:

`sed -i '/vhilmjpo/d'`

Any idea of how to do this? I was thinking probably a regex to match only between the php tags, something like `<?php $vhilmjpo[.+?]\?>`, and replace all of that with an empty string.

Comment: Don't use your sed command. It will remove the malicious code + the eventual html that is on the same line.

Comment: I know, but how to do it then? sed is supposed to also replace only substrings on a line, but I need it to use a regex to find the substring to replace

Comment: Restore a clean backup if your server is hacked.

Comment: This might help: [Website hacked, how to remove malicious code with SED / GREP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28317990/3776858)

Comment: @Cyrus I can only restore the core files, but not all my custom work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one:

```
sed '1{s/<?php \$vhilmjpo\([^?]\|??*[^?>]\)*?>//}' file
```

and if it works as expected then add the -i switch.

details:

```
1   # if the first line is processed then: 
{
    s/<?php \$vhilmjpo\([^?]\|??*[^?>]\)*?>// # replace from the opening tag followed
                                # by "$vhilmjpo" until the next closing tag
}
```

Comment: it didn't work :( can you explain what that command does? I understand the regex - sort of - but not the rest

Comment: `[^?]*` means "anything but the question mark zero or more times"?

Comment: @andrux: yes, exactly. I think it should suffice but it's also possible to be more explicit.

Comment: I also just tried this: `sed '{s/<\?php \$vhilmjpo[^?]*\?>//}' file.php` but it still didn't work

Comment: @andrux: you don't have to escape the question mark in BRE, it's a literal character. I tested the command and it works well. Eventually replace the space in the pattern by `  *` (two spaces and the quantifier `*`)

Comment: could you try it with the real thing? I copied the file contents into this gist: https://gist.github.com/andruxnet/b4bf4148374f65d3b3e9bb3e07e7e285

Comment: @andrux: ok I take a look.

Comment: @andrux: there are other question marks that are not part of the closing tag. I edited my pattern to take it in account.

Comment: That last one worked! How can I do it for all files in the directory? just remove the file name?

Comment: I did it like this with the find command: `find . -name '*.php' | xargs sed -i '1{s/<?php \$vhilmjpo\([^?]\|??*[^?>]\)*?>//}'` thanks!!

Comment: @andrux: you can shorten the sed command like this: `sed '1s/<?php \$vhilmjpo\([^?]\|?[^>]\)*??*>//'`